# Subscribers not added to publication list OR All Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, publicationlist

I've just tried to send an email to a data extension of 572 people. I created a new publication list for this.

When I did a send preview, in the part where you choose which recipient to preview the send of, a lot of the entries appeared as 'Invalid Recipient'. And then sure enough when I did a guided send of the email, using my new publication list, it only sent (and added to the publication list) 222 of the 572 people. I also notice that those people haven't been added to All Subscribers either.

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning, the data extension is populated by a CloudPages form and consists entirely of new subscribers that have mostly never been in our instance of SFMC before.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Invalid Recipient' error usually means that the email address is not valid.  This could be that there is an unrecognized special character, that the recipients domain is not accepted by SFMC (e.g. .mortgage, .ninja, etc.), sometimes even a simple space at the beginning or end can mess this up.

Keep in mind, that List Detective is only done prior to a send on Data Extensions, compared to pre-import on Lists. Importing through the UI into a DE can catch some, importing via a form, especially using Upsert or API calls, usually don't.

As these recipients are not valid in the eyes of SFMC, they are not sent to and therefore were not added to pub list (only adds those that were sent to) nor all subscribers (as they are not valid recipients - also only added from DE when sent to).

There are other reasons that a person can be an 'Invalid Recipient' - but usually it involves the email address.  If you have difficulty, you can contact SFMC support and they should be able to help you find what the issue is with your data.